# How to unset session on close page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

Using `jQuery` or whatever then how can i unset session only and only if the visitor close the page

```
unset($_SESSION['foo']);
```

I know the only way is in Javascript to detect that kind of stuff are `onunload` & `onbeforeunload` events

so how can i apply it to unset `$_SESSION['foo']` on closing the page

*But why i wanna to unset session if the visitor will close the page ?*

i will apply it in my simple website that based on watching youtube videos 
to prevent visitors open up `watching.php` many many times 
so i will force them to close it first before calling new video to watch
so my idea is to drop session and if found will print error message
but the problem will be how to free this session so i need help of `js` to do it
on page `watching.php`

Thanks a lot

Comment: Looks like this is too much server intensive. Something like a Long Polling!

Comment: for your healthy do not comment saying "what if user disabled javascript" :)

Comment: ^ That's a good one too! :P I didn't think about that!

Comment: @PraveenKumar thank you for your comment but the website is so simple of only 10 videos and of 1K visitors no one will get hurts if i did this :)

Comment: what if user disabled javascript ?

Comment: @user3038548 See if you tried out my answer.

Comment: PHP sessions automatically close when the page is closed, so what is your point? apart from `unset`, why wouldn't you use `session_destroy()` ?

Comment: As has been discussed countless times before, there is no reliable way whatsoever to do this. Once your server has sent the page to the client, the server has no reliable way of knowing what the client does with that page data, how long it keeps the page open or anything like that.

Comment: @larssy1 Nope, PHP sessions are not automatically destroyed when the page is closed,  that's impossible. What *may* be discarded is the session cookie on the client-side, but the server side session data stays for a while. But even the cookie retention policies of browsers are changing.

Comment: @PraveenKumar i'm testing it now

Comment: @larssy1 i will drop session on opening the page and will free it on closing the page so that the visitor can watch more videos

Comment: @deceze haha my bad, guess my own framework took care for me that the entire time and forgot about it..

Comment: @user3038548, it seems to me like you need to rethink your website's structure. Doesn't sound ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is too much server intensive. Something like a Long Polling! Also, PHP Sessions get automatically destroyed when the window is closed. But still if you insist, you can use something like attaching an AJAX Call with the event `onbeforeunload` this way:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    $.getScript("killsession.php");
});
```

This gets a JavaScript before the window is closed and in your `killsession.php`, you can give a delay with `sleep()` and you can unset the session. Your code will be like:

```
<?php
    unset($_SESSION)
    session_destroy();
    sleep(5);
?>
```

Let me again warn you, **this is really a bad practise** and consumes the server cycles!!!

Comment: thanks a lot and it works perfect and i truly understand that you warning me and guide me for best and safe method but with my website simplicity it won't hurts the server .. thanks once again